# Converting from NFA to a regular expression.

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

[image]

This is a NFA, I have been working to covert it to a regular expression. After I'am done, I arrive at an expression as follows

$$
\left(((a\cup b)a^*b) (ba^*b)^*a\right)^*  \left(((a\cup b)a^*b) (ba^*b)^*\right)
$$

Now, I really doubt if the answere is correct if anyone could help.
I used the state removal method.

Comment: If I counted parentheses correctly, the regular expression doesn't seem to accept an empty string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am going to write $S_i$ for the set of strings that cause the machine to go from the start state into state $i$.

From the diagram of the machine, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\def\a{\mathtt{a}}\def\b{\mathtt{b}}
S_1 & = \epsilon + S_3\a \\
S_2 & = S_1(\a+\b) + S_2\a + S_3\b \\
S_3 & = S_2\b
\end{align}$$

(This part is crucial, and if you don't find this obvious, and don't see where I got these equations, leave a comment so I can explain it.)

After this it is all mechanical.  Substituting $S_3$ into the equations for $S_1$ and $S_2$ gives:

$$\begin{align}
S_1 & = \epsilon + \color{blue}{S_2\b}\a \\
S_2 & = S_1(\a+\b) + S_2\a + \color{blue}{S_2\b}\b \\
    & = \color{darkred}{S_1(\a+\b) + S_2(\a + \b\b)} \\
S_3 & = S_2\b
\end{align}$$

We can eliminate $S_2$ from its definition using the rule that says that if $X = p + Xq$ then $X = pq^*$:

$$\begin{align}
S_1 & = \epsilon + S_2\b\a \\
S_2 & = S_1(\a+\b) + S_2(\a + \b\b) \\
    & = \color{darkred}{S_1(\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*} \\
S_3 & = S_2\b
\end{align}$$

Then we put the definition of $S_2$ into $S_1$ and apply the $X = p + Xq\implies  X = pq^*$ transformation to it:

$$\begin{align}
S_1 & = \epsilon + \color{blue}{S_1(\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*}\b\a \\
    & = \color{darkred}{\left((\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b\a\right)^*}\\
S_2 & = S_1(\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^* \\
S_3 & = S_2\b
\end{align}$$

Now we have an explicit formula for $S_1$ (which it's not hard to see is correct), we could substitute this into the equations for $S_2$ and $S_3$ to get explicit formulas for the strings accepted in those states, but what we really want is to know the strings accepted by the entire automaton, which is exactly $$\begin{align}S_1 + S_3 & = S_1 + S_2\b \\ & = S_1 + S_1(\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b \\ & = S_1(\epsilon + (\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b)\end{align}$$

and since $S_1 =  \left((\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b\a\right)^*$, then answer is that the automaton accepts

> $$\left((\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b\a\right)^* (\epsilon + (\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b). $$

That first term, $\left((\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b\a\right)$, will always take the machine from the start state around the loop and back to the start state; after doing that some number of times, the machine can accept immediately (that's the $\epsilon$) or can proceed to state 3 via $(\a+\b)(\a + \b\b)^*\b)$.

Comment: Nice exposition of the technique.

Comment: Good job. You got the same answer as I did and saved me the trouble of writing it up (not to mention that my answer wouldn't have been as clear as yours). Congrats.

Comment: Thanks!  I attribute my success to my early decision to `\def\a{\mathtt{a}}\def\b{\mathtt{b}}`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys really. Can anyone share me links to such methods of conversion.

Comment: @MJD I agree, `\mathtt` font is best for elements of an alphabet or other terminals.

Comment: The language $K^*L$ is always a solution to the equation $X = KX + L$, but it is the unique solution only if $1 \notin K$. If $1 \in K$, then all the languages of the form $K^*M$ where $M$ contains $L$ are also solutions. Fortunately, one can show that this situation never occurs when the algorithm nicely presented by MJD is used.

Answer (score 2):

MJD’s excellent answer illustrates a general technique for solving this sort of problem, but I think that it’s also worth pointing out what’s wrong with the regular expression that you got. The expression

$$\Big(\big((a\cup b)a^*b\big)(ba^*b)^*a\Big)^*\tag{1}$$

captures every word that gets accepted at state $1$, and the expression

$$\Big(\big((a\cup b)a^*b\big)(ba^*b)^*\Big)$$

captures everything that gets accepted at state $3$ without revisiting state $1$, so

$$\Big(\big((a\cup b)a^*b\big)(ba^*b)^*a\Big)^*\Big(\big((a\cup b)a^*b\big)(ba^*b)^*\Big)\tag{2}$$

captures everything that gets accepted at state $3$. The union of $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives you what you want, and then an obvious application of distributivity lets you simplify it to

$$\Big(\big((a\cup b)a^*b\big)(ba^*b)^*a\Big)^*\Big(\epsilon\cup\big((a\cup b)a^*b\big)(ba^*b)^*\Big)\;.$$

Thus, you actually had all of the major pieces; you just didn’t put them together quite right.