# Convert NFA with only accepting states to regular expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

Suppose you wanted to find a Regular Expression that defines the language accepted by the folowing Finite State Automaton. Where S1 and S2 are both accepting states.

[image]

How would I go on doing this?

Comment: There are two final states which intervene with each-other. This is what confuses me

Comment: What do you mean by "intervene"?  Do you know what it means to say that some string is accepted by an NFA?

Answer (score 3):

An NFA with only accepting states will accept the input, no matter what the input is.  Every string over its input alphabet is accepted. Do you know how to write a regular expression for any string over an alphabet?

---

Your comment  “There are two final states which intervene with each-other”. I am not sure what you mean by "intervene". An NFA may have several accepting states. When it has finished reading the input, if it could have finished in an accepting state, it accepts the input. There might be different computations which finish in different accepting states; that doesn't matter; it accepts the input if there is even one possible computation that finishes in an accepting state.

Comment: I was hoping by using the Transitive Closure Method (or any other appropriate method) that you can show me how to solve for the regular expression.

Comment: I described a method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474460/converting-from-nfa-to-a-regular-expression/474483#474483) which might be what you want.

Comment: Rkij = Rk−1ij + Rk−1ik (Rk−1kk )∗(Rk−1)ij

Is this what I have to do? Where Rkij represents the set of all strings that transition the
automaton

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Kleenes Theorm. To solve for the regex by proof

Answer (score 2):

Your automaton accepts any string of 0's and 1's.

Therefore the regular expression is {0, 1}*.

Or posix style: [01]*.

Comment: But how can I 'prove' this?

Comment: All strings in {0,1}* are accepted since the automaton accepts 0, 1, and end-of-string in all states. No other symbols (than 0 and 1) are accepted by the automaton, therefore no other strings then the ones contained in {0,1}* can be accepted. Qed.